# How to build a rectangle from two points using R and sf?

Tags: r

I want to build a rectangle, using R and the package sf,
this rectangle must start and end at two given points:

```
library(sf)
library(units)

>     point1$geometry
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -73.51295 ymin: 45.529 xmax: -73.51295 ymax: 45.529
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
POINT (-73.51295 45.529)
>     point2$geometry
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -73.51347 ymin: 45.52816 xmax: -73.51347 ymax: 45.52816
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
POINT (-73.51347 45.52816)
```

I define then the center, and the rectangle sizes

```
    center <- st_point(c((st_coordinates(point1)[1] + st_coordinates(point2)[1]) / 2,
                         (st_coordinates(point1)[2] + st_coordinates(point2)[2]) / 2))
    half_width <- as.numeric(st_distance(point1, point2) / 2)
    constant_half_height <- 100 / 111000  # 1 degree is approximately 111,000 meters
    half_width <- half_width / 111000  # 1 degree is approximately 111,000 meters
constant_half_height <- set_units(100, "meters")
```

and I build the rectangle

```
 corners <- rbind(
      st_coordinates(center) + c(-half_width, -constant_half_height),
      st_coordinates(center) + c(half_width, -constant_half_height),
      st_coordinates(center) + c(half_width, constant_half_height),
      st_coordinates(center) + c(-half_width, constant_half_height),
      st_coordinates(center) + c(-half_width, -constant_half_height)
    )
    
    rectangle <- st_polygon(list(st_linestring(corners)))
```

But I cannot have the correct rectangle, as I want it to follow the points azymuthal angle

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a line from `point1` to `point2` and add a buffer with flat line ends, you should end up with the described rectangle (*/../must start and end at two given points /../ follow the points azymuthal angle /../*). Though for such buffer options, you'd need to disable s2 ( `sf_use_s2(use_s2 = FALSE)` ) or work with projected coordinates.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)

point1 <- 
  data.frame(geometry = "POINT (-73.51295 45.529)") |> 
  st_as_sf(wkt = "geometry", crs = "WGS84") 
point2 <-
  data.frame(geometry = "POINT (-73.51347 45.52816)") |> 
  st_as_sf(wkt = "geometry", crs = "WGS84") 

# transform to projected CRS first; and back to WGS84, if needed
poly_sf <- 
  rbind(point1, point2) |> 
  # UTM 18N
  st_transform(32618) |>
  st_combine() |>
  st_cast("LINESTRING") |>
  st_buffer(dist = 10, endCapStyle="FLAT") |>
  st_transform("WGS84")

st_as_text(poly_sf)
#> [1] "POLYGON ((-73.51335 45.52812, -73.51359 45.5282, -73.51307 45.52904, -73.51283 45.52896, -73.51335 45.52812))"

ggplot() + 
  annotation_map_tile(zoomin = 0 ) +
  geom_sf(data = poly_sf, alpha = 0.6, fill = "gold") +
  geom_sf(data = rbind(point1, point2), size = 3) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Exactly what I needed, in fact a smarter solution. The transformation   st_transform(32618) is intended to allow for a metric buffer?

Comment: Well, without transforming to projected CRS while having s2 enabled (the default) you would still be able to set buffer distance in meters, but apparently `endCapStyle` has no effect so you'd get a round buffer at both ends.  And there would also be warnings when using geographic coordinates with  `st_buffer()`